# React Select Async

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-select

I'm trying to use React Select Async (https://react-select.com/home#async) passing the options conditionally, but without success. Something like:

[AsyncSelect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cab68.png)

Follow CodeSandbox link:
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-loadoptions-conditionally-oeimx)

Help me please?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What does this condition do? and why did you define it inside loadoptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs [here](https://react-select.com/props#async-props) you need to have 'defaultOptions' and 'loadOptions' expecting a promise.

1. Add `defaultOptions` and `loadOptions={loadOptions}`

   ```
   <AsyncSelect
      cacheOptions
      loadOptions={loadOptions}
      defaultOptions
      onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
    />
   ```
2. Add the condition in the `loadOptions` function

   ```
   const loadOptions = (inputValue, callback) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       if (conditionally === 0) {
         callback(filterColors(inputValue));
       } else return {};
     }, 1000);
   };
   ```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-loadoptions-conditionally-forked-qu7i1?file=/src/App.js:370-548)